# Complicated hierarchical control at WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, tree, wpf-controls

Good day! I have just started to learn WPF. There are standard features to build UI like below? In WinForms would have to create complicated custom control for this:

[image]

What the approach may be used in WPF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TreeView can be used for this approach. The item container styles should be customized as in the link below,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17025/Custom-TreeView-Layout-in-WPF

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using Listbox Control also.

**Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="DecoraSnap.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized" >
<Window.Resources>
    <Style  TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border>
                        <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Margin="100,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Border Height="50" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <TextBlock  FontWeight="Bold" Text="Meassage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0"/>
    </Border>
    <Separator Height="1" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="50"></Separator>
    <Border x:Name="BorderWidth" Width="1"  Background="Black"   ></Border>
    <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding RequestList}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"   x:Name="lst">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid x:Name="UniformGrid1" Height="{Binding ElementName=lst,Path=ActualHeight}" Loaded="UniformGrid1_Loaded_1"  Columns="1" ></UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Separator Width="50" Height="1" Background="Black"></Separator>
                        <Border Height="50" Width="100"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                            <TextBlock  FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Reaquest}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Border Background="Black" Height="1"  Width="50"></Border>
                        <!--You can implement border width like "UniformGrid1_Loaded_1" event -->
                        <Border Width="1" Background="Black"  Height="235" ></Border>
                        <ListBox   Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
                            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <UniformGrid x:Name="Uniformgrid2"  Columns="1"></UniformGrid>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Separator Width="50" Height="1" Background="Black"></Separator>
                                        <Grid Height="40" Width="100" >
                                            <Border  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                                                <TextBlock  FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Separator Width="50" Height="1" Background="Black"></Separator>
                                        <Grid Height="100" Width="100" >
                                            <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Fill="LightYellow" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1,2"></Rectangle>
                                            <TextBlock  FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Silver" Text="{Binding SameName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

**c# code**

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{                         
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Meassage> RequestList = new List<Meassage>();

        RequestList.Add(new Meassage()
        {
            Reaquest = "request",
            Models = new List<Commands>(){new Commands(){ Name = "command", SameName="command"},
                                          new Commands(){Name = "Metainfo", SameName="MetaInfo"},
                                          new Commands(){Name = "data", SameName="result" },}
        });

        RequestList.Add(new Meassage()
        {
            Reaquest = "response",
            Models = new List<Commands>(){new Commands(){ Name = "command", SameName="command"},
                                          new Commands(){Name = "Metainfo", SameName="MetaInfo"},
                                          new Commands(){Name = "data", SameName="result" },}
        });

        lst.ItemsSource = RequestList;
    }

    private void UniformGrid1_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UniformGrid un = sender as UniformGrid;          
        var ab= un.ActualHeight;
        var ItemsCount = un.Children.Count;
        var SingleHeight = ab/ItemsCount;
        BorderWidth.Height = SingleHeight * (ItemsCount - 1);
    }    

}

public class Meassage
{
    public string Reaquest { get; set; }

    public List<Commands> Models { get; set; }
}

public class Commands
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SameName{ get; set; }

}
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As XAML Lover has mentioned a TreeView control will be a better option here. You can use it with HierarchicalDataTemplate, where you can set the ItemsSource and bind to your view model.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035(v=vs.95).aspx

The example in the link uses a simple TextBlock to display the item Title. If you have to add additional items like a context menu for the tree view item this could be added within the HieraichalDataTemplate. Then to update the look and feel you will have to customize TreeViewItem style or the ItemsContainerStyle. You could add icons here and also customise the IsExpanded property if you need to keep the tree opened when loaded. The tree view would also allow you to navigate through the control and find a child item from a node.